# Integration by Parts? - Variable Manipulation

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

> $$\int x^3f''(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ Solve using Integration by Parts.
>   \begin{align}
> u&=x^3\qquad\mathrm{d}v=f''(x^2) \\
> \mathrm{d}u&=3x^2\qquad v=f'(x^2) \\
> &=x^3f'(x)-\int f'(x^2)3x^2 \\
> u&=3x^2\quad\mathrm{d}v=f'(x^2) \\
> \mathrm{d}u&=6x \qquad v=f(x^2) \\
> &=x^3f'(x^2)-[3x^2f(x^2)-\int f(x^2)6x]
> \end{align}
>
> No clue what do from here as the correct answer is:
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}(x^2f'(x^2)-f(x^2))+C$$

Can you guys think of anything? I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start with a small change of variable (just to make life easier) since $$I=\int x^3f''(x^2)~dx=\frac 12\int x^2 f''(x) 2x dx$$ S0, let $x^2=y$, $2x\,dx=dy$ which make $$I=\frac 12\int y\,f''(y) \, dy$$ Now, one integration by parts $$u=y\implies u'=dy$$ $$dv=f''(y)dy\implies v=f'(y)$$ So $$2I=u\, v-\int v\,u'=y \,f'(y)-\int f'(y)\,dy=y \,f'(y)-f(y)+C$$ Go back to $x$ using $y=x^2$.

Comment: This substitution has the merit that it makes the parts application a "usual" one in which one has $f'(y)$ rather than the cumbersome $f'(x^2)$ to deal with. And +1.

Comment: @coffeemath. Thank you ! At my age, I can only handle simple problems. Back to serious, as set and as you wrote, the problem, as set, was tricky (to me, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The derivative of $f'(x^2)$ is $f''(x^2) \cdot 2x$ using the chain rule. (it isn't just $f'(x^2)$ as you have it now.) So at your first step you need to use up one of the $x$'s from the $x^3$ factor, and adjust for the extra power of 2. With this idea applied twice it may work better.

Comment: How would you go about finding the integral instead of guessing and checking a derivative? I never was taught that.

Comment: I know about Substitution and everything but I don't know how to apply it in a "f(x)" sense.

Comment: When there is an undetermined function as here, the best way is guess and check. For example since the derivative of $f(x^2)$ is $f'(x^2)\cdot 2x,$ it follows the antiderivative of $2xf'(x^2)$ would be $f(x^2).$ Note that one *could* just start with the given answer and take its derivative using the chain rule, but of course that working backward method might not seem motivated, and can't be done without the answer being already known. But I think integration by parts twice can be made to work for this.

Comment: So guess and check it is...