# How to use Substitution in an Abstract sense?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, integration-by-parts

Based on my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638407/integration-by-parts-variable-manipulation/1638414#1638414): (somewhat related to it)

$$\int f''(x^2)~dx$$

How would you go about and find the **integral** in an *abstract* sense as you can do the following with **derivatives** using chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[f'(x^2)]$$
$$=f''(x^2)2x$$

I kind of call the above *abstract* as I think of it because we're not given what $f(x)$ actually equals?

Comment: So, what do you mean by 'abstract'?

Comment: @phatty Like without us being given the equation but rather its "f(x)" version.

Comment: For me personally, much of it is familiarity with the theory behind why integration was developed. However, what if I gave you $f''(x^2) \dot 2x = g(x)$ and asked for the integral? What would you do then?

Comment: @phatty No clue...

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts on the integral

$$\int f''(x^2)\,dx=\int \frac1{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(f'(x^2)\right)\,dx$$

with $u=1/2x$ and $v=f'(x^2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int f''(x^2)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2x}f'(x^2)+\int \frac{1}{2x^2}f'(x^2)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2x}f'(x^2)+\int \frac{1}{4x^3}\frac{df(x^2)}{dx}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, integrating by parts the integral in $(1)$ with $u=1/(4x^3)$ and $v=f(x^2)$ yields

$$\int f''(x^2)\,dx=\frac{1}{2x}f'(x^2)+\frac{1}{4x^3}f(x^2)+\frac34\int \frac{f(x^2)}{x^4}\,dx$$

Comment: Shouldn't your first step be $\int f''(x^2)\,dx=\int\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(f'(x^2)\bigr)\,dx$? (Now I see that this is probably what you mean)

Comment: @mickep Yes, of course.  Thank you for catching the typo!  +1 - Mark